# Read a file in CodeIgniter Controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to read a file inside CodeIgniter framework, it means in controller, My code is given below, But this doesn't work, I am a bit newbie here, can you guys guide me how to read file inside the controller?

```
$fp = fopen("id_rsa.pem", "r");
$priv_key = fread($fp, 8192);
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: You need the file helper. http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/file_helper.html

Comment: id_rsa.pem is in the controller folder? Pass full path there

Comment: Daimos i too pass the full path there then also i doesnt help, is there any specific location that we should place the file and access in codeigniter.

Comment: Have you read any of the documentation?  http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/file_helper.html

Comment: CodeIgniter File Helper `read_file($file)` is marked as deprecated in their documentation in favor of PHP native `file_get_contents()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you have set base_url in config.php 
you can load a file like this in your controller

```
public function load_file()
{
  // you need to load the url helper to call base_url()
  $this->load->helper("url");
  // you can change the location of your file wherever you want
  $MyFile = file_get_contents(base_url()."application/controllers/readme.txt");
  var_dump($MyFile);
  //etc...
}
```

example with json file  using google api

```
 public function load_file_via_api()
    {
       $json = file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?key=AIzaSyBdiYy5i2sI5HSkLYy54xoYIXn0M8OgGoA&id=DniEWhn7fvA&part=snippet&fields=items(snippet(title))');
       $obj = json_decode($json);
       print '<pre>' . print_r($obj) . '</pre>';
    }
```

read more about file_get_contents here http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

hope that helps

Answer (score 2):

You can try this script.. and also load the helper library

```
$this->load->helper('file');
$image_path = '/path/to/image/file';
$this->output->set_content_type(get_mime_by_extension($image_path));
$this->output->set_output(file_get_contents($image_path));
```

Answer (score 2):

> $fp=file_get_contents(APPPATH . 'controllers/id_rsa.pem');

You can see the content by running the function below

```
var_dump($fp);
```

Comment: worked perfectly !! I was working with a Codeigniter project and it needed APPPATH instead of base_url. I tried using complete url and blah blah blah... but in the end APPPATH worked just perfect !!